# Wordpress posts order by "Searched term" and by "post rating"

Tags: wordpress, sorting, element

So on my websites sidebar I want to put small filter form that will allow to filter posts by specific search terms and sort them by rating.

So for search part I use this workaround. Which is not perfect but works fine. It's just regular search:

```html
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="">
<div>
<label for="s"></label><br/>
<select value="" name="s" id="s" >
<option value="town1">town1</option>
<option value="town2">town2</option>
 <option value="town4">town4</option>
<option value="town5">town5</option>
</select>
<select name="test1">
    <option value="ASC">ASC</option>
    <option value="DSC">DSC</option>
  </select>
<input onclick="myfunction()" type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Find" />
</div>
</form>
```

But I have issue with ASC/DSC sorting by rating. The idea is that in each post I have different numeric value (raiting) that is assign to `<p>`  element
For example:

- post1: `<p id="test">5.5<p>`
- post2: `<p id="test">0.5<p>`
- post3: `<p id="test">3.5<p>`
- post4: `<p id="test">1.5<p>`

So I want to give user ability to search posts by town name (this function works already) and sort by raiting (ASC or DSC), and want to not just echo post title lists but show posts in regular manner (like: title, excerpts etc.)

So far sorting by raiting is messing everything, because I have no idea how to do that if I have to sort it by `<p>` IDs and how to connect this 2 rules: search and sorting.

Myfunction code:

```
    <?php
function myfunction( ) {
$args = array(
    'orderby' => jQuery('#test'),
    'order'   => 'DESC',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
}
?>
```

Comment: Please include the `myfunction()` code in your question

Comment: I have updated question

Answer (score 0):

Obviously `jQuery('#test')` is not going to work like that in PHP. Also using `onclick="myfunction()"` to call a PHP function is impossible. JS is executed on the client machine and PHP is executed on the server. This would never work.

**Calling a PHP function with JS is impossible, unless you use AJAX.**

```
<body>
    <form method="get" id="searchform" action="">
        <div>
            <label for="s"></label><br/>
            <select name="s" id="s">
                <option value="town1">town1</option>
                <!------------ -->
            </select>
            <select name="test1">
                <option value="ASC">ASC</option>
                <option value="DSC">DSC</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Find"/>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id="posts"></div>
    <script>
        jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
            $( "#searchsubmit" ).on( "click", function ( e ) {
                $.ajax( {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/admin_ajax.php",
                    data: {
                        action: "my_action",
                        orderby: $( "#s" ).val(),
                        order: $( "#test1" ).val()
                    },
                    success: function ( result ) {
                        $( "#posts" ).html( result );
                    }
                } );
                e.preventDefault();
            } );
        } );
    </script>
</body>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'myPHPFunction');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'myPHPFunction');

function myPHPFunction()
{
    if (!isset($_POST['orderby']) || !isset($_POST['order'])) {
        return;
    }

    $args = array(
        'orderby' => $_POST['orderby'],
        'order'   => $_POST['order'],
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // loop through your posts and echo the templates

    // stop execution
    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I have additional question regards JS part and PHP code. SO if we talk about Wordpress than this JS should be inserted in template header, right? Also I don't quiet get JS ajax part "url: "/your/php_script/url" what link should be entered there? (I believe thta php script should be entered in functions.php). So should I enter function.php there?

Comment: I ajusted the answer a bit to make it possible to put the PHP in in `functions.php` I also changed the `url` parameter from the AJAX request. You should put the JavaScript inside the `<body>` tag, right before `</body>`.

Comment: Hi, I tried this reworked codes. But for some reason now even search part don't work :D maybe am doing something wrong. I will describe step by step how I implementing codes so maybe You can spot where I'm messing up. Firstly I upload form code and JS in my sidebar by using php widget. Next I add php code to function.php. And noow for some reason nothing happens when I push "find" button